# AngularJs - не передает параметр в $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Я хочу получить id из url http://localhost/Inventory/Details/4b72c58e-ec01-4cc7-aa84-0763d9f9aad2 в контроллере. Использую $stateProvider, но $stateParams.id всегда пустой.
Вот мой модуль:

```
   'use strict';
(function (angular) {

    angular.module('inventory', [
        'ngMaterial',
        'common',
        'ui.router'
    ]).config(configuration);

    configuration.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function configuration($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
           .state('inventory.details', {
               url: '/Inventory/Details/:id',
               templateUrl: '/app/inventory/inventory.html',
                controller: 'InventoryController'
            });
    }
}(angular));
```

Вот контроллер:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('inventory').controller('InventoryController', InventoryController);
    InventoryController.$inject = ['$stateParams'];
    function InventoryController($stateParams) {
        var id = $stateParams.id;
```

**UPD**
Проблема была в объявлении контроллера:

```
<div ng-include="'/app/inventory/inventory.html'" ng-controller="InventoryController as vm"></div>
```

После замены на:

```
<div ui-view="page"></div>
```

все работает

Comment: а вообще запускается все? без ошибок в консоли?

Comment: да, все работает. ошибок нет.

Comment: А можете показать код, где вы вкладываете параметр при переходе на стэйт inventory.details?

Comment: Добавил в ответ код, с помощью которого вы можете отправить параметр в ваш стэйт.

Comment: попробуй сделать на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) минимальный пример, чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть

Comment: Сделай пример полный, который запустить можно.

Comment: @Grundy, зачем планкер, это же первый ангуляр - сниппетов хватает или jsfiddle.

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что ты не знаешь **что именно** в код не работает, код в принципе рабочий

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, не понял про что ты :-) Plunker, На случай если в коде несколько файлов, например шаблоны из файла подгружать, мне кажется там с этим намного проще сделано

Comment: @Grundy, я бы предпочёл, чтобы _минимальный_ пример помещался в один файл и обходился без подгрузки шаблонов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47385/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Comment: Вопросы - в вопросы, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Переход на другой стэйт должен быть примерно таким:

```
function go(detailId) {
   $state.go('inventory.details', { id: detailId });
}
```

Здесь в функцию go вы передаете нужный вам id и он будет передан в ваш стэйт `inventory.details`

Нужно указать в стэйте параметр явно.

```
function configuration($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('inventory.details', {
           url: '/Inventory/Details/:id',
           templateUrl: '/app/inventory/inventory.html',
           controller: 'InventoryController',
           params: { id: null }
        });
}
```

Comment: нет, не нужно. Это не обязательно

Comment: попробовала добавить, но результат все тот же

Comment: Пару дней назад была подобная проблема в ionic приложении. Мне помогло явное указание параметра в стейте.

Comment: @Grundy извиняюсь, да вы правы, если параметр указан в url его можно не указывать в params.